# class_weight giving worst results in Keras model. What could be the reason?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I'm working on an NLP Classification task with imbalanced data and the code:

```
df['target'] = le.fit_transform(df['CHAPTER'])
Y = df['target'].ravel()
classes = df['target'].nunique()

train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.1, stratify = Y, random_state = SEED)

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight = 'balanced',classes = np.unique(train_y),y = train_y)
class_weight_dict = dict(enumerate(class_weights))

vocab_size = 25000 

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size, filters = ' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(train_X))
train_X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_X)
val_X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_X)

train_X = pad_sequences(train_X, maxlen=maxlen)
val_X = pad_sequences(val_X, maxlen=maxlen)
```

Works fine and giving me an accuracy of around 70% when I do:

```
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=64, epochs = 30,
                    validation_split = 0.1,verbose = 1)
```

But the moment I use `class_weight=class_weight_dict` in `train` , my accuracy drops  from 70 to 30%. What could be the possible reason?  Am I doing something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `dict(enumerate(class_weights))` method, it creates a dictionary with keys starting from zero. In case if you don't have class labels that correspond to zero (or if you don't have any in that range, at all) this can be a problem. Below is a demonstration:

```
train_y = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]  # training labels: 1 and 2
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
    class_weight='balanced',
    classes=np.unique(train_y),
    y=train_y
    )
print(class_weights)
# array([0.83333333, 1.25      ])
```

Creating the dictionary as you've done it:

```
class_weight_dict = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
print(class_weight_dict)
# {0: 0.8333333333333334, 1: 1.25}
```

There is no class as `0` and the class weight for class `2` is missing.

Instead, you should do:

```
class_weight_dict = {label: weight for label, weight in zip(np.unique(train_y), class_weights)}
print(class_weight_dict)
# {1: 0.8333333333333334, 2: 1.25}
```

Comment: But I'm using `LabelEncoder`  as `df['target'] = le.fit_transform(df['CHAPTER'])
Y = df['target'].ravel() ` so I think it creates class names starting from 0 to all the way `n-1`